# Unity 3d PowerBar

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have been making endless jumping game.

It is lacking powerbar.. I have managed to make one but it does not scale with the screen change.. I tried to use canvas to world screen but bar won't face the direction you click..

So like the longer you hold left mouse click, more power it has and it faces the direction you click.. Atleast it should do that, and i does but only on one screen size.

It looks likes this:
http://prntscr.com/b6z5wn

So this is the code i am currently using..

```
function Start ()
{
powerFill_startPos = powerFill.transform.localPosition.x;
powerFillAccel = 770 * Time.deltaTime;
}

function Update ()
{
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && collision.onPlatform == true && delete.jurinoFlag == true)
{
    bar_back.enabled = true;
    powerFill_Image.enabled = true;
    var moveDirection : Vector3 = gameObject.transform.position - Input.mousePosition;
    if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
    {
        var angle : float = Mathf.Atan2(moveDirection.y, moveDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        angle -= 180;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }
    powerFill.transform.localPosition.x += powerFillAccel;
}
else
{
    bar_back.enabled = false;
    powerFill.transform.localPosition.x = powerFill_startPos;
    powerFill_Image.enabled = false;  
}
}
```

I would very much appreciate any help i can get so i can finish the game and publish it :)
Thanks for taking time and replying. Have a nice day!

Comment: `delete` is a keyword in C++. It is not a good idea to use it as a class or variable name. The chances of your app getting rejected in the Google App store is high. Even if you managed to submit it, you may not be able to update it afterwards. As for your question, learn C#.

Comment: Not much of a help...Its like i would ask if someone can help me ride a bike and you say, just learn to drive..

Comment: Its an advice. That's why I put it in the comment section instead of the answer section. This is also why no one is helping you. Most people here use C# and wouldn't spend their time answering Unity unityscript questions. This would have been answered long ago if you used C#. Anyways, good luck with Unity and unityscript.